# How to iterate List<Map<String, Object>> and add the key and value dynamically in another hash map in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to iterate the `List<Map<String, Object>>` and want to check if the **code** is "approved" or not - if **code** is having value **"approved"** then I would like to add **"id"** as **Key** and **"date"** as **Value** in another hashMap.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> prodIds = ((List<Map<String, Object>>) myIds.get("result"));
```

**This prodIds returns below set of records:**

```
[{id=[14766724], Date=[1999-01-01]}, {id=[49295837], code=[approved], Date=[2003-04-01]}]

[{id=[58761474621], code=[approved], Date=[2017-09-30]}, {id=[3368781], code=[Cancelled], Date=[2014-01-01]}, {id=[48843224], code=[Cancelled], Date=[2009-01-01]}]
```

I want the output something like this: If code is "approved" - my new hash map should have value like below:

```
map.put("49295837", "2003-04-01")
map.put("58761474621", "2017-09-30")
```

**Java Code**

```
List<Map<String, Object>> prodIds = ((List<Map<String, Object>>) myIds.get("result"));
System.out.println("prodIds : " +prodIds ); 
//  [{id=[14766724], Date=[1999-01-01]}, {id=[49295837], code=[approved], Date=[2003-04-01]}]
// [{id=[58761474621], code=[approved], Date=[2017-09-30]}, {id=[3368781], code=[Cancelled], Date=[2014-01-01]}, {id=[48843224], code=[Cancelled], Date=[2009-01-01]}]


Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map<String, Object> map : prodIds) { 
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) { 
            String key = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println("Key : " +key);

            String value = (String) entry.getValue();
             System.out.println(" Value : " +value);
        }
    }
```

I'm having difficulty how to put the key(id) and value(Date) dynamically if the code value is "approved" into new hash map. It would be really helpful if someone can help me with this.

Appreciated your help in advance!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can determine by your example, this should work.  But for each `Map<String,Object>` I need to know what `Object` is (e.g. `String`, `List<>`, etc).

I am assuming they are lists. If I'm wrong you will get a `ClassCastException`

```
    public static Map<String, String>
            getApproved(List<Map<String, Object>> prodIds) {
        Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map<String, Object> map : prodIds) {
            if (map.containsKey("code") &&
            ((List<String>) map.get("code")).get(0)
                    .equals("approved")) {
                newMap.put(((List<String>) map.get("id")).get(0),
                        (String) ((List<String>) map.get("Date"))
                                .get(0));
            }
        }
        return newMap;
    }

    Map<String, String> newMap = getApproved(prodIds);
    newMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
58761474621=2017-09-30
49295837=2003-04-01
```

It would help if you could describe all your data structures.  Like what is the `Object` type of map?

Comment: Hi - This won't work rite entry.getKey("code")? Because I used map.entrySet())

Comment: Look at my updated answer.  I think this will work.  But why are there [ ] around your dates?  Is that a list of one item.  Same thing for code values.  I need to know what each of you maps looks like structure wise.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But Map<String,String> will not work because my actual structure is Map<String, Object> which prints this  -  [{id=[14766724], Date=[1999-01-01]}, {id=[49295837], code=[approved], Date=[2003-04-01]}]

Comment: What is the type of the Object?  Just referring to it as Object is not sufficient.  Is it a List, or what?  And if so List<String> list<MyClass> list of something else.  Be specific!

Comment: Its List<MyClass>

Comment: Can you post the class definition?  It's necessary to know how to access the fields.

Comment: you example code looks good but I'm getting NullPointer Exception because in the following list this id 14766724 doesn't have code so its failing with NullPointer exception  [{id=[14766724], Date=[1999-01-01]}, {id=[49295837], code=[approved], Date=[2003-04-01]}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210072/discussion-between-marty-and-wjs).